Python subprocess usnig rsync is syncing extra data
I am using watchdog to monitor files and move them from a directory using rsync.  I overwrite the on_modified method.  Rsync is syncing more than it should.  The destinationDir = /home/pi/Desktop/destination.
The sourceFile are passed in one at a time.
 /home/pi/Desktop/source/one.txt
 /home/pi/Desktop/source/two.txt
 /home/pi/Desktop/source/three.txt
 /home/pi/Desktop/source/four.txt

def check_directory(directory):
    for f in directory.iterdir():
        #updating the files so on_modified gets triggered
        f.touch()

def on_modified(event):
    move_file(event.src_path)

def move_file(sourceFile):
    args = ['rsync','-hav',sourceFile,destinationDir,'--remove-source-files']
    subprocess.call(args)

Rsync is working the args line is below.
['rsync','-hav','/home/pi/Desktop/source/one.txt','/home/pi/Desktop/destination','--remove-source-files']
It does move all of the files.  However after sending the last file it then rsync the empty source directory. The source directory is never updated with a time via touch.  But rsync is moving the directory over. What am I doing incorrectly.

Because, rsync treats the given path (/home/pi/Desktop/source/one.txt) as a source file or directory, and when the directory becomes empty, it processes the empty directory. Instead add a function like...
import os

def move_file(sourceFile):

    # Check if the path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(sourceFile):  
        args = ['rsync', '-hav', sourceFile, destinationDir, '--remove-source-files']
        subprocess.call(args)

